# Css3 Transition Blur Flickering edges

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add an effect where if you click a button it blurs the background, but the original problem was that the edges where white for some reason, so i pushed them out by using negative margins which worked, but then when i tried to animate the blur and the edges seem to came back then disappear when the animation is done causing a flickering effect?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xq2ohL4x/

```
$(function(){
    $("#clickme").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $(".image").css("-webkit-filter", "blur(18px)");
    },1000); 
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced :)

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you. Change your transition to this.

```
transition: 2s -webkit-filter linear;
```